# How can I resize and style images in Outlook for Mac 2011?

Tags: macos, microsoft-office, microsoft-outlook-2011, office-for-mac

Outlook for Mac 2011 doesn't appear to have any way of resizing or otherwise styling (cropping, adding borders, etc.) images that are dropped into the body of the email.  I used this heavily in Outlook 2003, and it really made including images easier than having to edit photos in an external tool.  Surely this functionality hasn't been removed?  If it's there, where is it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sorry for a negative answer, but [Resize image in Outlook for Mac 2011](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/mac/forum/macoffice2011-macoutlook/resize-image-in-outlook-for-mac-2011/416f0dd0-4e58-4ebb-99e9-e2ae45068aaf?msgId=8f780533-d4fc-4df6-8936-4ec9eca32f19) says :

> Sorry, no. You'll need to size your images prior to placing them into
>   your Outlook message.
>
> the Windows version of Outlook has had many years and versions to
>   incorporate features. The Outlook for Mac version is new as of Office
>   2011 and not everything could be included. Sending feedback to
>   Microsoft will allow them to prioritize development of feature
>   requests from users.

The answer seems to be : Send your feedback and hope for the future.

Comment: so so sad.  feedback provided to MS, bounty provided to you.

Comment: lame. what kind of answer is that

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Absolutely ridiculous that it isn't supported, but good to know.

Comment: @Rampant: This answer was correct in 2011, but might no longer apply.

Comment: @harrymc unless I'm simply missing it, there's still no option to resize images from within Outlook 15.4. Outlook 2014 for Windows has an option to "Resize images when sending," but that only reduces the file size, not the actual onscreen proportions.

Comment: @Rampant: Unfortunate that this answer is still correct.

Comment: FYI, to anyone looking, I'm on Outlook 2016 for Mac and still doesn't appear to

Comment: It 2016 and you still can't resize an image in Outlook. Another MS fail!

Answer (score 2):

With Automator that's part of Lion, you can actually create a *Service* (not an app) so that when you right-click, you have a new menu (ex: “resize pic”) that does the job without having to drag & drop the pics on an annoying icon on the Finder desktop.

In my case, I now use it to resize some chosen pics and add them straight as an attachment to an Outlook 2011 message (as the photo resize feature is badly missing under Outlook).

So I can right click and I have “compress and send via email” when a pic is selected.

It’s clean indeed. Automator is quite powerful in that respect. Should you need more info, please write a comment and I'll elaborate a bit.

Comment: ... a comment.  Silly not to have this out in the open...

Answer (score 1):

The work around I use is to compose the message in Word, which allows you to resize images in the document, and then copy everything to my email message.

Comment: Ah, that works :) While I never had high expectation from MS (and never will), this is a neat workaround. Thank you!